# How to render code in shiny module by passing an environment variable?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to render UI from code input through shiny modules. But I'm not able to figure out why it's not working. There are no errors, so it is hard to understand where the reactivity is breaking.

Code

````
library(shinyAce)
library(reactlog)

reactlog_enable()

codeUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(htmlOutput(ns("output")))
}

codeSE <- function(id, active_id, code, env) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 output$output <- renderUI({
                   req(id == active_id(), cancelOutput = TRUE)
                   eval()
                   eval_code <- paste0("\n```{r echo = TRUE, comment = NA}\n", code(), "\n```\n")
                   HTML(knitr::knit2html(text = eval_code, fragment.only = TRUE, quiet = TRUE, env = env()))
                 })
             })
}

 ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("output"),
  aceEditor("code", mode = "r", height = "50px"),
  actionButton("eval", "Evaluate"),
  div(id = "#add_here")
)


env <- environment()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  counter <- 1
      active_id <- reactiveVal()
      observeEvent(input$eval, {
    req(code)
      current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
      active_id(current_id)
      codeSE(id = current_id, active_id = active_id, code = input$code, env = env)
     insertUI(selector = "#add_here",ui = codeUI(current_id))
      counter <<- counter + 1
      runjs('
      document.getElementById("end").scrollIntoView();
    ')
})   } 
   shinyApp(ui, server)
````

The goal of the app is to enter code in the input and show output as divs upon clicking evaluate.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've had several issues:

- in the `div`, the `id` has to be `add_here`, not `#add_here`. The `#` in `insertUI` is for `jQuery`
- `env` is a normal variable, not a function. So it's `env` instead of `env()`
- when you call your module, you use `code = input$code`. That means that you pass an evaluated reactive, so it's not reactive any more. Therefore, you need to use `code` instead of `code()` in your module

````
library(shinyAce)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

codeUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(htmlOutput(ns("output")))
}

codeSE <- function(id, active_id, code, env) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 output$output <- renderUI({
                   req(id == active_id(), cancelOutput = TRUE)
                   eval_code <- paste0("\n```{r echo = TRUE, comment = NA}\n", code, "\n```\n")
                   HTML(knitr::knit2html(text = eval_code, fragment.only = TRUE, quiet = TRUE, envir = env))
                 })
               })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("output"),
  aceEditor("code", mode = "r", height = "50px"),
  actionButton("eval", "Evaluate"),
  div(id = "add_here")
)


env <- environment()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  counter <- 1
  active_id <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$eval, {
    req(code)
    current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
    active_id(current_id)
    codeSE(id = current_id, active_id = active_id, code = input$code, env = env)
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here",ui = codeUI(current_id))
    counter <<- counter + 1
    runjs('
      document.getElementById("end").scrollIntoView();
    ')
  })   } 
shinyApp(ui, server)
````